# Splitting a List by multiple conditions

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Using hibernate i'm bringing a list of results from a sample table `ANIMALS` . The hibernate method looks like this :

```
...
List<Animals> animalList= null;
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY COLOR , HEIGHT , AGRESSIVE; ");
            animalList= query.list();
        }
...
```

An example of the result set would be the following :

```
NAME    COLOR   HEIGHT  AGRESSIVE
---------------------------------
JIMMY   BLACK   SHORT   NO
RIPPER  BLACK   SHORT   YES
GOOFY   BLACK   TALL    NO
MURPHY  BLACK   TALL    YES
PAUL    WHITE   SHORT   NO
ROB     WHITE   SHORT   YES
BOBBY   WHITE   TALL    NO
JACK    WHITE   TALL    YES
```

My actual result list has a minimum of 100,000 records so parsing the list and executing `list.add(..)` for each is not very wise ;
What i would want to do is split the result set into 8 smaller lists containing each combination of `COLOR`,`HEIGHT` and`AGGRESSIVE`.
After that the lists will be given as parameter to a method in order to execute a series of operations.

I can only use Java 1.6 or lower.
My main target is to escape from the `IndexOutOfBounds` measures i took and the crazy ammount of `IF's` like the following :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < animalList.size(); i++) {
previousAnimal = animals.get(i-1);
currentAnimal = animals.get(i);
nextAnimal = animals.get(i+1);
    ...//extra code
    IF ( previousAnimal.getColor() != currentAnimal.getColor() || previousAnimal.getHeight() != currentAnimal.getColor() || previousAnimal.getAgressive() != currentAnimal.getAgressive() )
    ...//extra code
    IF ( currentAnimal.getColor() != nextAnimal.getColor() || currentAnimal.getHeight() != nextAnimal.getColor() || currentAnimal.getAgressive() != nextAnimal.getAgressive() )
    ...//extra code
```

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you could do it using the Stream API. If you're using Java 7 or prior, then use a library like quaere or similar

Comment: Filter the query , you can use Criteria of Criteria API

Comment: Or put everything in a `MultiMap` and use a key that is a tuple of your properties with a consistent `hascode()` method.

Comment: Are you interested in the whole set and you want to filter it into different data structure(s) after the SQL query, or do you want a small set from the 1,000,000 records you are getting based on some criteria?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ it doesn't matter if the result is split in SQL or in JAVA . I'm only interested in the fastest solution .  I can't filter inside the query after a certain property because in time the properties may became Blue And Red instead of Black And White or so ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function to identify animals with similar characteristics:

```
...
List<Animals> animalList= null;
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT a.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COLOR, HEIGHT, AGRESSIVE) GRP FROM animals a ORDER BY COLOR, HEIGHT, AGRESSIVE; ");
            animalList= query.list();
        }
...
```

An example of the result set would be the following :

```
NAME    COLOR   HEIGHT  AGRESSIVE GRP
-------------------------------------
JIMMY   BLACK   SHORT   NO          1
RIPPER  BLACK   SHORT   YES         2
GOOFY   BLACK   TALL    NO          3
MURPHY  BLACK   TALL    YES         4
PAUL    WHITE   SHORT   NO          5
ROB     WHITE   SHORT   YES         6
BOBBY   WHITE   TALL    NO          7
JACK    WHITE   TALL    YES         8
```

Where each distinct combination of `Color`, `Height` and `Aggressive` would yield a distinct value for the `GRP` column.  Then you could simplify your other code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < animalList.size(); i++) {
previousAnimal = animals.get(i-1);
currentAnimal = animals.get(i);
nextAnimal = animals.get(i+1);
    ...//extra code
    IF ( previousAnimal.getGrp() != currentAnimal.getGrp() )
    ...//extra code
    IF ( currentAnimal.getGrp() != nextAnimal.getGrp() )
    ...//extra code
```